# How do you add an rpath to an executable in cmake on build (not install) on OSX?

Tags: macos, cmake

So, if you already have a binary, you can add an rpath to it on OSX using the 'install_name_tool', as so:

```
install_name_tool -add_rpath @executable_path/blah
```

xcode does this automatically when you're building an application bundle.

I know that in cmake you can use this to set the install_name of the shared library:

```
set_target_properties(nshared PROPERTIES BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH 1 INSTALL_NAME_DIR "@rpath")
```

My question is, **what's the equivalent of this to add an rpath to a binary?**

(for the 'why would you do that?' amongst you, go look at the otool -l on any of the apps in your Applications/ folder and you'll see plenty of apps with entries like:

```
Load command 15
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 36
         path @executable_path/../../Frameworks/
```

This is standard practice. I'm just trying to do it in cmake)

Comment: A more general question is why techniques described in the official [documentation](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling) to set `RPATH` for targets apparently don't work for executables?

Comment: I wonder if someone can update this 10 year old question for cmake 3.14 and higher, when  bunch of `RPATH` variables were introduced. Which I still can't get to work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use a [POST_BUILD command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) to add an `LC_RPATH` load command to the built executable:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET executable 
    POST_BUILD COMMAND 
    ${CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL} -add_rpath "@executable_path/../../Frameworks/"
    $<TARGET_FILE:executable>)
```

The variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL` contains the path to the `install_name_tool` executable under Darwin.

Comment: In my experience, this solution causes an error on any build after the first build from a clean directory. The custom POST_BUILD command runs on every build whether the target is out-of-date or not, and install_name_tool returns a non-zero exit status and displays a message that the rpath value being added already exists in the target file (because it was added during the first build). CMake's documentation seems to indicate that the POST_BUILD command will only run if the target is out of date, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: A more general question is why techniques described in the official [documentation](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling) to set `RPATH` for targets apparently don't work for executables?

Comment: I simply can't get what's written in the documentation you've linked to, to work.

Comment: I wonder if someone can update this 10 year old question/answer for cmake 3.14 and higher, when  bunch of `RPATH` variables were introduced. Which I still can't get to work.

Comment: For those who using higher version of cmake, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43551483/how-to-set-rpath-in-cmake/)

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to set `XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` property to the desired value:

```
set_target_properties(TargetName PROPERTIES
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS "@executable_path/blah"
```

this will generate XCode project with the setting Runpath Search Paths set to the value.