# Running cmake project with dynamic libraries

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

I am working on a project which uses a 3rd party closed source SDK that consists of a single shared library and corresponding header file. I'm trying to avoid adding the library to the search path so I can try compiling the project against several different versions of the library for testing.

My question is how do I handle shared libraries so the project builds and runs nicely? I can build the project, but the newly created executable can not locate the shared library I need. It will run if I copy the shared library to the same folder as the executable, but I want to avoid that doing that extra step manually to keep things easier for other developers. What would be a good way to manage shared library dependencies so that when the project gets built it can run even without the shared libraries in the search path?

Here are the relavent parts of my `CMakeLists.txt` file showing how I am locating the shared library:

```
add_library(theSDK SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties( theSDK PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/TheSDK/lib/libSDK.dylib )
add_executable(myProject ${myProject_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries (myProject theSDK)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on on Linux or Mac and the location of the shared library you are depending on is know you can use the rpath to include a library search path in your executable. See e.g.:

- [How do you add an rpath to an executable in cmake on build (not install) on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656033/how-do-you-add-an-rpath-to-an-executable-in-cmake-on-build-not-install-on-osx)
- http://www.semipol.de/archives/356

Alternatively, you could configure a script for executing the program which then dynamically adjusts PATH (Windows), LD_LIBRARY_PATH (Linux) or DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (Mac) before executing your binary. These environment variables are used to resolve shared libraries at runtime.

Comment: That looks like it will work great for me, but the developers I am working with need to run it on a Windows machine. I'll try it out and see how it goes.