# Can @rpath be modified in a makefile with g++ on OSX?

Tags: macos, gcc, makefile, dynamic-linking

I am trying to dynamically link to a custom dynamic library in an OSX application. For various reasons, I don't want to have specify environment variables after the build. I want my build environment to provide everything needed to run the application.

I am compiling the application with gcc using a makefile (actually, I a script that makes calls to qmake and does some automated editing.). On linux I would just do:

```
-Wl,-rpath,<path/to/dynamic/library>
```

but for whatever reason OSX doesn't abide by these rules. I keep getting

```
@rpath/mylib.dylib Library not loaded
```

when I try to run the app.

I hope this is clear. I want the app itself to know where to look for `mylib.dylib`. I know how to do this in Xcode with LLVM, but it would be nice if I could do it with a makefile and gcc as well. I don't want to have to setup a whole Xcode project for simple little apps like this (of which I need to make many that link to my library). Qmake etc. is far more convenient.

Comment: Still poking around and I can't find anything illuminating. It seems that whenever anyone asks 'how do I set the Runpath Search Paths option in a makefile' the answer is inevitably: 'use Xcode'.

Comment: See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656033/how-do-you-add-an-rpath-to-an-executable-in-cmake-on-build-not-install-on-osx?rq=1)

Comment: in my case the libraries are in .../app/lib folder. I gave the rpath until the .../app folder and it worked. when I see the output of my executable using the otool -L binary, it printed @rpath/lib/*dllname*. You can try that

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this for SFML libraries present outside the project directory, and it worked for me.

```
CC = g++
INC_PATH = ./inc
LIB_PATH = ./../SFML/build/lib
LIBS = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window
CFLAGS = -std=c++17

all:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp -I$(INC_PATH) -o executable -L$(LIB_PATH) $(LIBS)
    install_name_tool -add_rpath @executable_path/../SFML/build/lib executable
```