# How to set RPATH in CMAKE?

Tags: cmake

I wish to build and install a software locally to the `$HOME/.local/` path instead of a system-wide `/usr/` folder. The software uses CMAKE for compilation.

After installation, the software binaries and libraries get stored in `$HOME/.local/bin/` and `$HOME/.local/lib/`, respectively. However, when I try to run the program, it throws an error that the required library is not found (which, by the way, is present in `$HOME/.local/lib/`).

The program works fine if I set the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `$HOME/.local/lib`. But I don't want to do this. Hence, instead of this, I would like to know how to specify the `RPATH` variable (which would point to `$HOME/.local/lib`) while compiling the software using CMAKE.

Kindly help.

Comment: Documentation: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I am using the following two lines in the CMakefile

```
set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 1)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")
```

(the first one is required only if you use MacOSX)

Comment: `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` is a predefined list, so I can see scenarios where it would be better to do `list( APPEND CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib )`.  If you `include( GNUInstallDirs )` you could also `list( APPEND CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} )`.  I am a CMake novice though, and I'm just getting into it, so if someone sees an issue with the above, do please let me know.

Comment: @PfunnyGuy thanks for the `list( APPEND ...)` advice. Maybe put that up as an alternative answer?

Answer (score 8):

`CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` is a predefined list, so I can see scenarios where it would be better to do

```
list( APPEND CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib )
```

If you `include( GNUInstallDirs )` you could also

```
list( APPEND CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} )
```

I am a CMake novice though, so if someone sees an issue with the above please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

you may also use:

`set(CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH "/my/libs/location")`

*specifying runtime path (RPATH) entries to add to binaries linked in the build tree (for platforms that support it). The entries will not be used for binaries in the install tree. See also the CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH variable.*

Answer (score 0):

`CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH` works for me, or setting the linker rpah.

- Solution 1: set the rpath before `add_executable`

```
project(app)
set(RPATH "/lib/custom")
list(APPEND CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH ${RPATH})
...
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${SOURCES}
    ${HEADERS}
)
```

- Solution 2: change linker rpath

```
set(RPATH "/lib/custom")
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}
       PROPERTIES
       LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-rpath,${RPATH}"
)
```